# Counting The Number of Variants of a Rock Paper Scissors Game with more than 3 Weapons

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory

The fact that the traditional variant of the game of rock paper scissors has 3 weapons is well known. However with 3 weapons there can be 2 variants:

```
Variant 1:
    Rock beats Scissors
    Scissors beat Paper
    Paper beats Rock
Variant 2: 
    Rock beats Paper
    Paper beats Scissors
    Scissors beat Rock
```

Now, if one wants to increase the number of weapons, the number must be increased to an odd number. So variants that satisfy the following criteria are balanced:

- There are $n$ weapons; $\{n|n = 2k+1 \land k \in \mathbb{N} \gt 0\}$
- Each weapon is weak against $k$ weapons, and strong against the other $k$.

My question is: **For $n$ weapons, how many variants can there be?**

Using [an algorithm I've formulated](https://github.com/Aphrontos/Ngolaniirrarat), I found that there are 24 variants for 5 weapons, or in general: $(n-1)!$ variants for $n$ weapons.

Summary of the algorithm:

1. Generate the Strengths and Weaknesses Labelled Adjacency Matrix (SWLAM)
2. Switch the rows and then the columns of the SWLAM
3. Relabel the rows and columns.

For illustrations and examples, please refer to the given link above. What I'm not sure of is whether or not the algorithm can generate all the variants.

Comment: For the classic variant, $k=0$ but that doesn't make sense because each weapon is weak and strong against $1$ weapon respectively. $n$ should be $2k+1$.

Comment: @MathIsNice1729 I edited the criteria.

Comment: FYI: You may be interested in the R[ock]P[aper]S[cissors] Variants pages [here (umop.com)](https://www.umop.com/rps.htm). (The author even devised gestures for a complete RPS-101.) It's also worth noting that the five-weapon variant "Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock" has some notoriety.

Comment: Can you un-accept heropup's answer? It turns out to be wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When $n\ge 7$, your method will not generate all possible variants. As $n$ gets larger, the proportion of variants you get becomes vanishingly small. This problem is analyzed in the paper [Rock-Paper-Scissors meets Borromean Rings](https://chamberland.math.grinnell.edu/papers/rps.pdf) by Marc Chamberland and Eugene A. Herman.

When $n=7$, there are three possible isomorphism types for the RPS graph, shown below. The below image is taken from that paper. Your method will generate all permutations of the left graph, but will miss all permutations of the middle and right graphs.

[image]

Comment: Does it mean that the formula $(n-1)!$ is not correct?

Comment: @user Indeed, $(n-1)!$ undershoots the number by a lot. I have no idea why heropup thought the graphs were unique up to isomorphism.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Because traditional RPS variants can always be judged by mapping the plays to indexes $a$ and $b$, subtracting them modulo $n$, then mapping $0$ to “draw”, $1$ to $(n-1)/2$ as “win” and $(n+1)/2$ to $n-1$ as “loss”. But, as you noted, there are more possibilities than the traditional.

Comment: This is also why the proper name is “Rock Paper Scissors Spock Lizard”; the order of names of a traditional RPS variant unambiguously describes the rules.

Comment: Oh wow... Time for some reading. Does the number of isomorphisms increase beyond this?

Comment: Indeed. The number of isomorphism types is listed in https://oeis.org/A096368, and you can see it grows very quickly. There's no way to generate them all, as $n$ gets large.@Aphrontos